# Node.js Why will it only print one at a time

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

Im using node.js to list out items from a txt file. I have it to print them out from terminal, however i want it to accept more parameters, as of now it accepts them but only prints one out(the last one) i want it to print each item in the parameter and list them out.

```js
// Make sure we got a filename on the command line.
if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.log('Usage: node ' + process.argv[1] + ' FILENAME');
  process.exit(1);
}
// Read the file and print its contents. And split into an array after each space
var fs = require('fs') , filename = process.argv[2];
var array = fs.readFileSync('dependencies.txt').toString().split('\n');
 //console.log(array[0]);

   


if(process.argv.length >= 3){
  for(var j = 3; j < process.argv.length; j++)
  var test = process.argv[j];
  functionName(test);
}
  



function functionName(test){    
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
   var pattern = /([^\s]+)/g;
   var line = pattern.exec(array[i]);
 if(line && test == line[0]){
 console.log(array[i]);
    }
  }
}




//fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
 // if (err) throw err;
 // console.log('OK: ' + filename);
 // console.log(data)
//});
```

[how it prints out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd39M.png)

Comment: did you expect to call `functionName` once for each iteration of that loop? because that's not what you're doing. instead `functionName(test);` happens after the loop has completed.

Comment: yes i need it to run through and print each item that has been called within terminal

Comment: so use proper `{` `}` when you have a for loop with multi lines. or make it a single line by removing `var test` line.

Comment: I got you now. Thanks man I've been staring at this for to long became deluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop can only contain one statement, so if you need more than one, you'll have to wrap it in a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).
(Thanks @paulpro)

I would just add a block statement for all for loops, it's more readable that way unless it was short enough to be readable on one line.

```
for(var j = 3; j < process.argv.length; j++) {
  //var test = process.argv[j];
  functionName(process.argv[j]);
}
```

```
let len = process.argv.length, j = 3;
for (;j<len;j++) functionName(process.argv[j]);
```

Comment: Specifically, a for loop always consists of exactly one statement, whether that is on multiple lines or one line, or the same line as the loop header. If you want more than one statement in a loop you need to use a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).